# change webservice address mid execution

Tags: c#, web-services

Using a webservice (Visual Studio 2012) that I added using the wizard (right click add web service reference) I added the following url
"http://onwww.org:8086/Plugins/Misc.onwww/Remote/NopService.svc"

I have another webservice that uses the same api, the webservices are the same in every respect same contract same everything.

"http://yadisrael.org:8086/Plugins/Misc.onwww/Remote/NopService.svc"

I would like to change the domain name in code during execution to another domain, how would I change the value ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could specify two different endpoint configurations in your config file, and then when you instantiate the service client for each different endpoint, call the constructor that takes [the overload that accepts an endpointConfigurationName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms574925.aspx). Alternatively, you could specify one endpoint configuration, and then call one of [the overloads that takes a remoteAddress or endpointAddress and the endpoint configuration name.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms574922.aspx)

Comment: the problem is I need to add to this list on a constant basis, I am making a nopcommerce plugin that will be used centrally